# How to get prefilled form field values in ngsubmit method?

Tags: angular, forms

I have a reactive form with 3 fields, two of the fields has default values and the fields are disabled to the user. User has to enter the value of third field and submit the form. When submitted, I only get the user entered value in form.value

```
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private userService: UserService) { 
    this.signUpForm = fb.group({
      'name': ['John Doe', Validators.required],
      'email': ['john@requantive.com', Validators.required],
      'phone': [null, Validators.required]
    });
  }
```

When i console log form.value on ngsubmit method I get the output as

{phone: "123456"}
phone: "123456"
**proto**: Object

Comment: in the ngOnInIt lifecycle method
````
ngOnInit() {
    this.signUpForm.get('name').disable();
    this.signUpForm.get('email').disable();

  }
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are disabling the Formcontrol using disabled method, use getRawValue() method to get all the values include disabled controls

**app.component.ts**

```
  this.signUpForm = fb.group({
      'name': [{value:'John Doe', disabled:true}, Validators.required],
      'email': [ {value:'john@requantive.com', disabled:true}, Validators.required],
      'phone': [null, Validators.required]
    });
```

**app.component.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="signUpForm">
  <input formControlName="name">
  <input formControlName="email">
  <input formControlName="phone">
</form>
formValue:{{signUpForm.getRawValue() | json}}
```

[ForMoreInfo](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#getrawvalue)

[Example Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bugwwx)